How to create multiple application ID apks with different firebase project using single code base
Background :

I am developing a kotlin android app linked to firebase , already uploaded to google playstore. I need to upload identical app to google playstore with a different id and a name with a fresh firebase account. And I don't want to maintain multiple code bases.

I did some research and foundout that using different product flavours in app level gradle I could create multiple apks with different application ID's.
Example : app/gradle
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}

The thing I want to know is this, I am planing to use different firebase project for each varient of apk
as an example lets say

com.google.abc - for this apk i need to link abc firebase project -> google-services_abc.json
com.google.def - for this apk i need to link edf firebase project -> google-services_def.json
com.google.ghi - for this apk i need to link ghi firebase project -> google-services_ghi.json

I need to maintain a single code base , but need to have different application ID to publish to playstore as different applications. And I need to let each app uses different firebase project.
Thank you
